# My Braixen switched gender when it evolved

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So I was just playing Pokemon Y. My Braixen (female) evolved yesterday and I just realized that its gender switched to male. How is that possible? Does Delphox have a 100% male gender ratio or something? 
 Please note though- I'm actually not exactly sure when it switched- I just noticed it, but I think it was at evolution. 
 I know that it's not a case of having mistook its gender when I first received my starter- I named it Aurora and even thought that I was lucky to have a girl Fennekin. So... can pokemon switch gender when they evolve? Is there a way to change it back?

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR Most likely, you misread Fennekin's gender.**

Delphox has the same 87.5% male-to-female ratio as its previous evolutions, and there's no known glitch that would cause it to change to male upon evolution. Bulbapedia keeps a [heavily researched list of all known XY glitches](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_glitches_in_Generation_VI), and none discovered have involved Pokemon gender changing on evolution.

The only Pokemon who has ever had a gender-change-related glitch is Azurill to Marill. Azurill having a 25% male ratio and Marill being 50% male meant 1/3 of all female Azurill would become male on evolution. However, this glitch only existed in Gen III-V, and was fixed in Gen VI, so it's very unlikely something similar would be happening to your Gen VI Delphox.